# Excessive item's render

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, react-virtualized

I'm using react-virtualized with CellMeasurer and a dynamic height like this
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-virtualized-list-with-random-height-ciwvq
But my data are more complex than what I used in the codesandbox.

I tried to render 2060 items with firefox and 14 items were rendered with no error
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7300656/58968174-e0b06e00-87b5-11e9-9810-1b79c24aa399.png

But with chrome it tried to render 658 items before my apps crashed
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7300656/58968208-f45bd480-87b5-11e9-9cf6-06636a3d56ea.png

I don't know why Chrome tries to render this amount of item when Firefox only render 14. My client only use chrome as their web browser

Unfortunately I can't show my code because it belongs to my company all I can say is I try to render an array of multiple object which has multiple object.

I'm using react and react-dom (16.4.1) and react-virtualized (9.21.1)

Thanks

Comment: you would have to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to be able to help you

Comment: I update my codesandbox but I can't reproduce my error with my company set of data. I tried with faker and this is the closest I can get.